# EAGLE - how to make ground planes to connect to the smaller PADS

Tags: ground, eaglecad, pad, polygon, connect

I cant fid how to configure the GND polygon to connect to smaller IC pads:

[image]

## EDIT

Following the @Dave Tweed answer the result is exactly as I need:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have to configure the plane to be made of a thinner track?

Comment: Set your thermal spoke width to a smaller value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a quirk with Eagle, but a polygon has a "width" associated with it, just like any other track. It sets the width of the aperture used to "paint" the fill inside the polygon. If this width is too large, then it can't paint the path to closely-spaced pads, as you have found.

The fix is to set the polygon to use a smaller width. This allows the polygon to flow into tighter spaces, before it gets blocked by the clearance rules.

Comment: Great. That is what I was looking for.